# Swift display an error message from enum parameter

Tags: swift, error-handling, enums

I have this error code enum

```
enum EYErrorCode: Error {
    case insufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: Int)
}
```

I want to display an error that says something like:

```
"Error - You need \(coinsNeeded) to perform this action"
```

But I am not sure how to make my error display the `coinsNeeded` parameter.

My code is as follows:

```
static func errorForCode(code: EYErrorCode) -> EYCustomError?
{
        switch code {
          case .insufficientFunds:
            let localizedDescription = NSLocalizedString("You do not have enough cash", comment: "insufficientFunds message")
            return EYCustomError.init(localizedTitle:nil, localizedDescription: localizedDescription, code:code)
        }
}


protocol EYErrorProtocol: Error {
    var localizedTitle: String { get }
    var localizedDescription: String { get }
    var code: Int { get }
}


public struct EYCustomError: EYErrorProtocol {
    var localizedTitle: String
    var localizedDescription: String
    var code: Int

    init(localizedTitle: String?, localizedDescription: String, code: EYErrorCode) {
        self.localizedTitle = localizedTitle ?? "Error"
        self.localizedDescription = localizedDescription
        let err = (code as NSError).code
        self.code = err
    }
}
```

My question:

How do I create a error that displays the insufficient funds (coinsNeeded) parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For enums with parameters, you can extract the associated values using the switch statement, like so..

```
switch code {
      case .insufficientFunds(let amount):
        let localizedDescription = NSLocalizedString("You do not have enough cash. Required amount: \(amount)", comment: "insufficientFunds message")
        return EYCustomError.init(localizedTitle:nil, localizedDescription: localizedDescription, code:code)
    }
```

See the Associated Values section of the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

Comment: I wasn't aware I could put parameters in switch case statements.  But I will try it.  It seems to work so I will accept it